# Prove that a polyrectangle in an open set has a superset polyrectangle.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, rectangles

> Theorem:
>
> Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Let $P \subset S$ be a polyrectangle. Then there exists another polyrectangle $P'$ such that $P \subset P' \subset S$.
>
> A polyrectangle is a union of rectangles. (Sets of the following form) $$\bigcup_j\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}[a_{j, k}, b_{j, k}]$$

I have already proved that any polyrectangle can be expressed as a union of disjoint rectangles, but it is difficult to consider rectangles inside an open set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $S$ is open and for each $j$ , $$\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}[a_{j, k}, b_{j, k}]\subseteq S$$ we can find $\epsilon_{j,k}>0$ such that $$\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}[a_{j, k}-\epsilon_{j,k}, b_{j, k}+\epsilon_{j,k}]\subseteq S$$

Comment: How can you guarantee that such $\epsilon_{j, k}$ exist?

Comment: Well since $S$ is open it contains an open neighbourhood of each of its points. Since we are in the metric space $\mathbb R^n$ that neighbourhood can be chosen as an $\epsilon$ - ball

Comment: but if you take the minimum of infinitely many numbers the result may be $0$

Comment: We are not taking a minimum of infinitely many numbers. Roughly speaking, for each interval $[a_{j,k},b_{j,k}]$ we are finding an open interval in $\mathbb R$ containing it and taking the product of all such open intervals.